# Adding dynamic Link to menu Item in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, menuitem, dynamic-links

I want to have 'Text only' in menu of my wordpress website without plugin.So how to set dynamic link to menu item in wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one

```
 add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'menu_link', 10, 2);

    function menu_link($items, $args) {

                  if ($args->menu == 'footer'){
                    $items .= '<li class="copyright "><a href="' . get_permalink()."/?text=1" . '">Text Only</a></li>';
                    $items .= '<li class="copyright "><a href="' ."print.php"."?Page=".get_the_ID().'">Print Page</a></li>';
                  }

        return $items;
        // return $items1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to recreate the complete menu walker to make it text only, or remove the anchor through jquery. But if you just want a menu item that doesn't link anywhere, create a normal link menu item, and instead of an actual link use #.